# Compare 2 lists in drools

Tags: drools

So I have 2 lists of strings - one in a CSV file and one is a comma separated string. I need to check if any of the string in the comma separated list is present in the list of strings in CSV file.

Ex - 
CSV - 
ABCD1,
ACCD2

Comma separated list - AEFG1,ACCD2.

If the above condition is true, then go to then part of the logic. I am not sure how to construct this in a DRL/DROOLS file.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: You need to read the file and process the lines one by one. Write a Java method for checking whether two lists of String meet the criterion.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write java code to compare these two fields, and call this java code form drl file as function. Go through [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/FunctionalProgrammingInDrools) for more details on drools function.